# Can you have ros2 python launch files in pure python packages?

Tags: python, ros2, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a package with:

```
ros2 pkg create --build-type ament_python lrs_exec
```

In that package I created a lcunh file according to https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Tutorials/Launch/Launch-system.html

The launch file is:

```
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node

def generate_launch_description():
    return LaunchDescription([
        Node(
            package='lrs_exec',
            output='screen',
            executable='resource',
            name='resource_agent'
        )
    ])
```

The executable is called resource.py and is in a sub-dir lrs_exec of the package lrs_exec.

Trying to run:

```
ros2 launch lrs_exec exec.launch.py
```

I get:

```
tompe@tpexps:~$ ros2 launch lrs_exec exec.launch.py
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/tompe/.ros/log/2022-01-24-15-02-45-557721-tpexps-4043650
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-2' coro=<LaunchService._process_one_event() done, defined at /opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py:226> exception=SubstitutionFailure("executable 'resource' not found on the libexec directory '/home/tompe/lrs2_ws/install/lrs_exec/lib/lrs_exec' ")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

So should this work or do I have to create a specific launch package as it was created in the launch turotial?  I tested with resource.py and no difference.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394953/can-you-have-ros2-python-launch-files-in-pure-python-packages?/) by [tompe17](https://answers.ros.org/users/22519/tompe17/) on ROS Answers with karma: 140 on 2022-01-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tompe17](https://answers.ros.org/users/22519/tompe17/) on 2022-01-24**:
Above I had manually created install/lrs_exec/lib/lrs_exec. The first error message was that the directory did not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So my mistake, I had forgotten to add to entry points in setup.py. The following:

```
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'resource = lrs_exec.resource:main'
    ],
},
```

fixed the problem. I am pretty new to ros2 and assumed I did not have to do these things to find the program.  Have now learned otherwise.

---

Originally posted by [tompe17](https://answers.ros.org/users/22519/tompe17/) with karma: 140 on 2022-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0